# Como acceder a una posición de una palabra char*

Tags: array, c, lista, string

Me encuentro realizando un programa que lea un archivo de entrada. Cada palabra se guarda en la siguiente variable:

```
char *token;
```

Un ejemplo de palabra puede ser: perro, gato, flamenco. Necesito saber como acceder a una determinada posición de esta palabra. Para perro, necesito lo siguiente:

```
token[0] = p
token[1] = e
token[2] = r
token[3] = r
token[4] = o
```

He intentado acceder a cada letra mediante token[i], pero al imprimir el resultado (printf), la consola no muestra nada:

```
void letraPalabra(char *token){
    char p = token[0];
    printf("letra:  %s", p); //este printf no me muestra nada en la consola
}
```

Token se rellena de la siguiente manera, antes de ser llamado por letraPalabra:

```
        if(fgets(buffer, 100, entrada)){
            char *token;
            token = strtok(buffer, " ");
            letraPalabra(token);
            while(token != NULL){
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                //letraPalabra(token);
            }           
        }
    }
```

No he logrado descubrir un método para hacer esto posible. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Honestamente no entiendo la pregunta. "*Necesito saber como acceder a una determinada posición de esta palabra*". En el ejemplo que pones ya estas accediendo a los elementos de `token`. Con `token[0]` estas accediendo a la posición 0, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Ya he intentado acceder a una posición determinada de la palabra mediante token[0], pero no he obtenido resultado. Edité recientemente la pregunta añadiendo lo que intenté hasta el momento. Gracias por el comentario

Comment: ¿Cómo se rellena `token` antes de la llamada a `letraPalabra`?

Comment: Se rellena en base a un archivo de entrada, donde hay palabras separadas con un carácter de espacio " ". La idea es acceder a cada palabra mediante el strtok que he añadido a la pregunta recientemente. Pero al acceder a cada letra de cada palabra tengo problemas. Gracias

Comment: Para imprimir un caracter debes usar `%c` y no `%s`.

Comment: @thecesaroswing619 `printf("letra:  %s", p);`. `%s` espera un `char*`, tu le das un `char`. Me impresiona que no te de un SIGSEGV. Tiene que ser `%c`.

Answer (score 2):

**Para recorrer un string carácter a carácter:**

```
 char cadena[] = "ESTO ES UNA CADENA DE PRUEBA";
 int i;
 printf("%s\n", cadena);
 for(i = 0; cadena[i]; i++)
 printf("%i %c \n",i, cadena[i]);
 return 0;
```

Comment: Tienes un error en el segundo printf.

Comment: @Mateo creo que ya esta solucionado

Comment: @Eric Aun tienes un error. Tiene que ser: `printf("%i %c \n",i, cadena[i]);`, no `printf("%i %s \n",i,cadena);`.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias, ya esta rectificado